Excel automatically changes =IMAGE() to =@IMAGE()
When I have an =IMAGE(<url>) formula in Google Sheets and export to Excel file, and then open it with Excel, Excel automatically converts it to =@IMAGE(<url>).
This breaks the formula. I can fix it by simply removing the @ and the image now renders correctly in Excel.
I inspected the .xlsx file before opening it in Excel and I can see that the formula is =IMAGE and not =@IMAGE, so I know that it is not Google Sheets that adds the @.
How do I prevent Excel from adding this @?

TL;DR

The inclusion or removal of the "@" is not relevant to the #NAME error you are seeing, but reflects the version of Excel you are running.
The formula is disabled because Excel protects users and the function contains an external URL and has never been explicitly validated in Excel.
There are a number of security permissions that first need to be approved and/or enabled in Excel in order to successfully use that function.  Some are in "Options" and some need to be approved via pop-ups on a formula-by-formula  basis.
Note that if you authorized the formula so that it worked, and then copied and pasted the working formula to another cell in the same worksheet, Excel would again block the functionality unless you approved new security warnings.
 




Excel automatically converts it to =@IMAGE().
This breaks the formula.

No, the addition of the @ symbol (see implicit intersection operator) does not break the formula.  The formula is valid in your version of Excel with or without that operator.

Excel performs a number of steps and modifications to files in the XLSX archive when using functions like IMAGE.
These are done when the function is calculated and include creating and saving a local (to the archive) thumbnail and performing various security checks.
Since the file is not really an Excel file but a file that has been generated to meet the parameters of an Excel file, the archive has limited features for a number of valid reasons.
Simply entering the affected cell in edit mode and then re-saving it with or without the @ symbol will allow Excel to perform all the necessary steps to validate the URL and import the image.

Comparison of XLSX Archives
An XLSX file is a ZIP compressed archive containing multiple files and folders. Microsoft XLSX archives are based on the Office Open XML Spreadsheet file format with additional Microsft-specific extensions (learn more).
Below, I compare multiple XLSX archives. Each is a single-worksheet spreadsheet with one cell, A1, populated with the following formula:
=@IMAGE("https://picsum.photos/100")

The Four XLSX Archives I Compared

Excel Web App
A new file is created in the web version of Excel. The formula is properly validated and the thumbnail image appears prior to saving.
Excel Desktop
A new file is created in the Desktop version of Excel. The formula is properly validated and the thumbnail image appears prior to saving.
Sheets Export
A new Google Sheets file is created containing the formula (without "@"). The formula is properly validated in Sheets and the thumbnail image appears prior to downloading/exporting as an XLSX archive.
Sheets Fixed
The Sheets-exported XLSX is opened in Excel Desktop and the formula in A1 is entered in edit mode and then saved using Enter (nothing is changed in the formula). Excel immediately displays security notifications, which are manually approved. The thumbnail appears and the file is immediately resaved.

Compare Archive Properties



Created In
Size
Folders
Files
                                                           




Excel Web
26.3 KB
9
17



Excel Desktop
23.3 KB
9
17



Sheets Export
  9.9 KB
7
10
❗Has missing and unique files


Sheets Fixed(resaved in Excel)
19.8 KB 
9 
17 
❗Resaved in Excel Desktop 



Archive File Tree




Files contained                         XLSX Version →in XLSX Archive ↓
ExcelWeb App
ExcelDesktop
SheetsExported as xlsx
Sheets FixedResaved in Excel




1
_rels.rels
✓
✓
✓
✓


2
[Content_Types].xml
✓
✓
✓
✓


3
docProps\app.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


4
docProps\core.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


5
xl_rels\workbook.xml.rels
✓
✓
✓
✓


6
xl\calcChain.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


7
xl\drawings\drawing1.xml


✅



8
xl\media\image1.jpeg
✓
✓
❌
✓


9
xl\metadata.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


10
xl\richData_rels\rdRichValueWebImage.xml.rels
✓
✓
❌
✓


11
xl\richData\rdrichvalue.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


12
xl\richData\rdrichvaluestructure.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


13
xl\richData\rdRichValueTypes.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


14
xl\richData\rdRichValueWebImage.xml
✓
✓
❌
✓


15
xl\sharedStrings.xml


✅



16
xl\styles.xml
✓
✓
✓
✓


17
xl\theme\theme1.xml
✓
✓
✓
✓


18
xl\workbook.xml
✓
✓
✓
✓


19
xl\worksheets_rels\sheet1.xml.rels


✅



20
xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml
✓
✓
✓
✓



Legend



Icon
Explanation




✓
Present in all tested XLSX archives


❌
Missing from Google Sheets exported XLSX


✅
Included only in Google Sheets exported XLSX




It breaks alright. It shows #NAME?

After I remove the @ sign, the image renders. Note that the file generated by Google sheets is a valid open xml file even though it was not generated by Excel

I added additional clarification to the beginning of the answer.   I am not arguing whether the formula returns the image or #NAME. What I was pointing gout is that the @ in the formula is not causing the error as you stated.  Entering the formula and resaving allows the security process to proceed, not the removal of the @.  You can test this for yourself.

I have allowed external content and editing.

The image only renders once I open the formula and press enter again.
But I have hundreds of cell images so I can't manually do that for all cells. That's why I consider Excel to fail.
Once I press enter on the formula, the image renders. If I save the file and open it again, the image now renders immediately, but only for images for which I have pressed enter in the formula bar for.

How can I get Excel to render all images in all cells without having to manually fix each cell one by one?

Also when I fix a given cell, Excel changes the markup from _xludf.IMAGE("https://.... to xlfn.SINGLE(_xlfn.IMAGE("https://..., this might have something to do with it

It changes a lot more than that.  Save a converted in Excel without fixing anything so that it modifies the archive to provide a baseline. Then make a copy of the updated file and use that one to "fix' one of the formulas. Then do a dif of the contents of the two archives (files/folder) as well as a dif of the files in the archive to see what all has changed. You're problem space is potentially quite broad and a solution might be on par with the scope of the manual fix.

You might consider creating a separate question  that is focused on a VBA script or something to generate the column formulas you need in Excel.    My answer was comprehensive but focused on "Excel automatically changes =IMAGE() to =@IMAGE() / How do I prevent Excel from adding a @?" and also I'm not a VBA guy.
